# Why n value stays 4 not matter what I entered in do while loop?

Tags: arrays, c, do-while

I should make the user to enter the integer elements of array , the array size is unknown because it can vary to user's desire. So I declared it as big `int a[81];` I should find the number of elements inputed, but not matter how much elements I enter it stays as 4. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    
    int i = 0, n;
    int a[81];
    
    printf("Zero cannot be the element  of array, but enter zero if you finished entering the elements of array. \n");
    printf("Enter the elements of array by whitespace each: ");
    
    do {
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
        i++;
       
    } while((a[i]) != 0);
    
    n = i + 1;
    printf("%i", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while((a[i]) != 0);` but you have already incremented `i`. The array has not been initialised so you are testing an *undefined* value.

Comment: You test `a[i] != 0` but `i` has already been incremented. So you're testing uninitialized memory, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `while (a[i-1] != 0)` is more accurate.

Comment: well, first things first... if you put data in `&a[i]`, then increase i `i++` and then compare `a[i]` you're not looking at the same data... likely uninitialized memory or so

Comment: Remove the `i++` and replace the `while((a[i]) != 0)` with `while((a[i++]) != 0)`. Or better, replace the entire loop with `while (i < 81 && scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1 && a[i++] != 0) { ; }`

Comment: The `n = i + 1` will be *one more* than the number of elements entered, which is `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Here is my solution to your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 81

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, a[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

    printf("Enter the elements of the array (enter 0 to stop)\n");
    do {
        printf(" ? ");
        scanf("%d", a+i); //a+i is the same as &a[i]
    } while(a[i++] != 0 && i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);

    /* i is going to also count the 0. That's why if the
       last added element is 0, we subtract 1 from the total elements */
    if(a[i-1] == 0)
        i--;

    printf("\nTotal entered elements in the array: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Some things worthy of note:

- When you have an array it's a good habit to use the preprocessor macro `#define` to set its size. You use it as `#define NAME VALUE` (in the code we have `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` for the `NAME` and `81` for the `VALUE`). It makes the code more readable and if you decide to change this value in the future, you have to change it in one place only. You can learn more about [Preprocessor Directives here](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)
- **Always** check if you reached the end of the array. In your code, the end user can enter numbers endlessly, as long as he doesn't enter the value `0`. Long story short, this can create problems.